# Strichartz Estimates for radial Klein-Gordon equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, hyperbolic-pde

I'm trying to prove global wellposedness for the Klein-Gordon-Equation with **radial** initial data. I'm therefore searching for/trying to prove strichartz estimates of the form: $$ ||e^{it\langle D\rangle}u||_{L^q_{t}L^r_{x}}\lesssim||\langle D\rangle^lu||_{L^{2}}$$ or $$||P_{L}((e^{it\langle D\rangle}u_{M})(e^{it\langle D\rangle}v_{N}))||_{L_{2}}\lesssim L^lM^mN^n||u_{M}||_{L^{2}}||v_{N}||_{L^{2}}$$ with indices $l,m,n$ as small as possible. Where $P_{L}$ is the Littlewoodpaley projector, $e^{it\langle D\rangle}$ the Propagator of the (mass 1) Klein-Gordon-Equation and $L,M,N$ frequencies.

I'm aware, that you have more admissible strichartz exponentens $(q,r)$ for the first kind of estimate if you have radial data (the result is outlined here: http://wiki.math.toronto.edu/DispersiveWiki/index.php/Strichartz_estimates) but I can't see whether/how that can help me since I will get the same $l$ as with none radial data. Am i missing something here?

Also I don't know how to proof the first inequalitity for non-radial-data. I know it is true for $2\leq  r<\infty$,  $2/q+n/r=n/2$,  $l=1/q-1/r+1/2$ and was told to find the proof in Delort and Fang(2000) but I can't. (I hope the proof will help me understand how I can improve the result for radial functions)

Comment: For the standard estimate (first inequality) I don't think you need to refer to something as high powered as Delort and Fang. The black box technique of Keel-Tao ("Endporint Strichartz estimates") essentially carries over. In the K-T paper they only explicitly treat Wave and Schrodinger; but if you insert the $L^1-L^\infty$ decay for Klein-Gordon (which you can get by stationary phase type estimates) you can interpolate exactly the same way against the energy conservation to get the estimates.

Comment: Note however, there is some caveat in 2 dimensions; see http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021782410001182 for a proof there. ; I am doubtful that you can get better $l$ in the radial case: the argument that sets the differentiability is essentially a scaling argument. You can do it while preserving the radiality of the data. That the $(q,r)$ exponents can be improved is due to that the obstruction there is due to the Knapp counterexample, which gets weakened in the radial cased.

Comment: Your second inequality will imply the spacetime $L^4$ Strichartz estimate. For Klein-Gordon that is compatible with dimension 2. But in the form it is stated it is best treated as a spacetime bilinear estimate. Since you are looking at the frequency restricted case, you can probably learn something from http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.5372 and http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5978. The two papers are for wave equations, but you can easily replace the wave-Sobolev spaces by $X^{s,b}$ spaces adapted to Klein-Gordon and use more-or-less the same techniques.

Comment: The fact in the papers of Selberg and collaborators they do angular restrictions should also help tell you where radial data can help.

Comment: 1. I can see, that the Knapp counterexample gets weakened, the thing I don't get is why it is at all useful that you get more (q,r) which are admissable. How can that help in proving wellposedness? The procedures I know of only use $L^4$ or $L^2$ estimates. 2. I looked deeply into the two papers you directed me to, I see that this can be applied to KGE, however I can't see what the angular restrictions got to do with radial data. The thing is that the procedure outlined there (and used in most of the other papers) relies only on intersections and not on the specific attributes of initial data.

Comment: 1. For the wellposedness problem of nonlinear equations, enlarging admissible ranges for (q,r) allows treating more types of nonlinearities. For an example see Klainerman-Machedon, "Spacetime estimates for null forms and the local existence theorem", CPAM (1993). In particular pay attention to Theorem 2, Theorem 3, Proposition 4, and Remark 1.

Comment: 2. The Fourier transform of radial functions are radial. The reason that angular cut-off are needed in general is that certain "worst-case scenario estimates" that occur, if you try to estimate naively without doing the cut-off, will give you a larger contribution than is actually there. If you know a priori that the functions are radial, certain of these worst-case scenario cannot occur, and you can get better estimates.

Comment: Another way to say this is that the angular cut-offs are designed to solve a particular problem (isolate certain types of interactions), and this problem is exaggerated when the data are not purely radial. So understanding why this procedure is needed in the paper will help you understand what you can get away with when the data is in fact radial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a complete set of Strichartz estimates for the nonradial KG equation in Lemma 3 in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmi/1049123084) by Machihara, Nakanishi and Ozawa. Let me add that, usually, in proofs of local or global well posedness for the wave or KG equation, the non-endpoint Strichartz estimates are more than enough. Thus the wider range of admissible indices in the radial case is not very helpful in general. It could be useful in some cases in which you expect for some reason a better result for radial data.